# DynamoDB: How to get the oldest items from a table

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm facing a problem with dynamo db. I have a table that would store a lot of items and at some point I need to retrieve the 5000 oldest items from that dynamo table.

I have two ideas about how to do it but I would like to know if they are good options or if there is a better way.

- First: Perform a scan on that table. Scan is an expensive operation but the objective can be achieved by getting all the items in the table (this is a problem because the amount of items can be huge) and then filtering in code the 5000 oldest (The items will have a date attribute).
- Second: Put all the items with the same PK and perform a query based on a SK (Date). The query operation is cheaper than the scan but is the same situation. The query will retrieve all the items with the same PK, for example 50.000 items, and I would get the first 5000 oldest because they are sorted previously by Dynamo.

This two options are inefficient because I am retrieving a lot of data for only take a small part.

There is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a frequent request pattern, then you can create an index with a static partition key, and then date as sort key.

| GSI1PK | GSI1SK | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01T00:00:000Z | data |
| 1 | 2022-03-01T00:00:000Z | data |
| 1 | 2022-04-01T00:00:000Z | data |
| 1 | 2022-05-01T00:00:000Z | data |
| 1 | 2022-06-01T00:00:000Z | data |

Now you do a `Query` on the index with a `Limit=5000` and you will efficiently get the latest 5000 items.

```
aws dynamodb query \
--table-name my-table \
--index-name my-index \
--key-condition-expression "#pk = :pk" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":pk":{"S":"1"}}' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#pk":"GSI1PK"}' \
--limit 5000
```